# Unable to update wpdb via PHP code

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress

I am trying to update my database value but I am unable to achieve this. Basically I am trying to update a fields meta_value but don't know where I am wrong. I have inserted the below code in my theme `functions.php` file. Below is the code.

```
function update_values () {
    global $wpdb;
    $update_query = $wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value='10,15' WHERE post_id='1981' AND meta_key='cuzd-prod-general-v'" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using $wpdb->update.

```
<?php $wpdb->update( $table, $data, $where, $format = null, $where_format = null ); ?>
```

From: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows

In your case:

```
$update_query = $wpdb->update( "wp_postmeta SET meta_value='10,15' WHERE post_id='1981' AND meta_key='cuzd-prod-general-v'" );
```

Comment: Maybe simpler is the answer:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta

Answer (score 0):

try this out. Its pretty simple

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'nickname', $uname );
```

You can get the user_id by using `get_current_user_id()` function as

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
```

So your complete code will be

```
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'nickname', $uname );
```

Your meta key is "cuzd-prod-general-v" so use that key instead of 'nickname'